# Span border displays weird

Tags: html, css, border

I made my first website page and it looks like this:
[image: pic1]

To do that nice title and that red `border` around I use the following code:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
div span {
  border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 5px;
}
div h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><span>This is a title</span></h1>
</div>
```

But when I have a longer title, the `border` display very weird, like this:
[image: pic2]

In this case, how would I style that title in order to get only one `border` for all the text, like in the first picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `border` to `h1` instead and remove it from `span` and set `display:inline-block` to `h1`

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
div h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  /* add this*/
  border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><span>This is a title</span></h1>
</div>
```

---

or I as mentioned earlier ( but you did say wasn't working for you) -- see [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37191184/2)

add `display:inline-block` to `span` because span is an inline element

```css
div span {
  border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block
}
div h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><span>This is a title</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The border is the same, 100% width. :(

Comment: The site isn't hosted. I have this one in my PC only.

Comment: did you check my both snippets in full page link?? Because they are both working, so must be some CSS of yours overriding it. Can you show the full code, HTML/CSS for this page ??

Comment: you are applying within a media query that is only to `(max-width: 660px)`, that's your problem. apply these rules before that media query

Comment: I moved that rules and the problem persists... :(

Comment: can you post your site live? that's the only solution I can see to easily help you out. Because the fix is already given, now it is a matter of debugging your whole site, which is already being more than Q&A ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `display` property of the `span` to be `inline-block`:

```
div span{
  border:2px solid rgba(250,0,0,.75);
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}
```